# Why doesn't TypeScript insist that someArray[0] can be undefined?

Tags: typescript

I have these two getters in my class:

```js
    get jobs(): Job[]
    {
        return Object.values(this.#jobs);
    }

    get job(): Job
    {
        return this.jobs[0];
    }
```

Why *doesn't* TypeScript 4.2.3 complain that `this.jobs[0]` can be `undefined`? It allows me to return it as `Job` from the second getter, but the array returned by `get jobs()` is in no way guaranteed to be non-empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` config value will add `undefined` to the type returned by an index access.

Comment: Hmm, now it seems that getting it to *stop* complaining is super difficult. It still complains in situations like `if (key in index) { index[key].foo(); }`, i.e. I explicitly runtime-check that the key is in the object but it still complains (and the object is `Record<string, SomeType>` so it can't have a undefined-under-key).

Comment: in these cases you can safely assert the type e.g. add `if (key in index) { index[key].foo() as SomeType; }`

Comment: You mean `(index[key] as SomeType).foo()`? I can do that, but I believe I shouldn't have to.

Comment: instead you could do something like: `const item = index[key]; if(item) { item.foo() }`

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. My theory is that TS treats all these operations (`key in obj`, `obj[key]`) as potentially overridable in a way that mutates the object, so it refuses even to assume that `key` is still in `obj` right after `key in obj` was momentarily seen to be true. But if you actually pick the value out and test it directly then it knows that the value couldn't have changed between test and usage.